# What is a correct way to chain import submodules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a project with following structure:

```
├── modules
│   ├── modulea.py
│   └── moduleb.py
└── program.py
```

program.py is the main executable, which imports module a like so

```
from modules import modulea
```

in modulea I would like to import something from moduleb. Now, logically, I should be doing `import moduleb` as it is in the same directory. But that would yield `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleb'`

So in order for this chain import to work, I either have to do `from modules import moduleb`. which angers IDEs as there is no "modules" directory around or `from . import moduleb` which angers pylint.

While both of the methods above work, they feel confusing and unpythonic as one is assuming that imports are going to happen from one level above and one is using relative imports where it doesn't seem necessary.

Is there a way to handle this with more grace?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can make `modules` a python package by creating a `__init__.py` file in it.

```
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── modulea.py
│   └── moduleb.py
└── program.py
```

Then use `from modules.moduleb import some_object` in `modulea`.